# Añadir listener en swift

Tags: swift, swift2

No entiendo quien es el que llama a los métodos de, por ejemplo,

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 1
    }
```

En java, para conectar un evento con su listener tenes que, al objeto, agregarle un, por ejemplo, .addActionListener(clase que gestiona el evento). Pero en swift, en iOS, no entiendo quien es el que llama a estos métodos y en que orden(hablando de tableViews).

En este código quiero agregar un evento al tableView, para que cuando se haga un scroll, se ejecute el código del método:

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    }
```

pero no logro entender como poner a escuchar al tableview...

[image: Código]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu clase implementa los protocolos `UITableViewDelegate` y `UITableViewDataSource`, por tanto, son estos protocolos los que se encargan de llamar a los metodos necesarios para inicializar tu TableView.

El metodo que mencionas `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` pertenece al protocolo `UITableViewDataSource`, echale un ojo a la documentacion de estos protocolos. [UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/) y [UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/).

Si estas un poco perdido con todo este tema de las tablas puedes echarle un ojo al tutorial de apple para [comenzar a desarrollar aplicaciones en iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH2-SW1).

Existe un metodo del protocolo `UIScrollViewDelegate` que se ejecuta cuando el tableView esta a punto de comenzar a hacer scrolling:

```
override func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print("scroll")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Te han contestado previamente de una forma muy correcta, pero voy a explicarte el tema de porqué debes realizar la herencia de la clase `UITableViewDelegate`

El **patrón de diseño Delegate** es una técnica en la que un objeto delega la responsabilidad de implementar un comportamiento específico a un objeto asociado en una relación inversa de responsabilidad.

Efectivamente, al estar implementando el protocolo `UITableViewDelegate`, indicas que tu ViewController es el delegado de esos métodos, por lo que UITableView delegará la responsabilidad de ejecutar sus comportamientos a tu clase ViewController, funcionando de un modo similar al Listener que indicas. Los métodos serán llamados cuando la clase `UITableView` avise a sus delegados (en tu caso, la clase ViewController) que han de ejecutarlos (similar -que no igual- al patrón Observer)

El patrón Delegate es muy usado en Swift y en Objective-C, por lo que te recomiendo que leas su estructura, implementación, comportamiento y usabilidad :)

[Aquí tienes un tutorial recomendado](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/)

Answer (score 0):

Para que esos métodos sean llamados, debes indicar quien será el delegado que "escuchará". Por ejemplo, en la clase donde tengas tu `UITableView` debes hacerlo tal que así:

```
tableView.delegate = self
```

De esta manera, ya se ejecutarán los métodos, que son llamados por el `UITableView`

Answer (score 0):

Te falta añadir la tabla a la vista, en el viewWillAppear() por ejemplo y añadir lo que te dice mhergon con el delegado. En cuantro se ejecute ese controlador la tabla te aparecerá con sus 4 elementos. 
El controlador al ver que tiene una tabla y que implementa los protocolos se ocupa de ejecutarlos. Si pones puntos de interrupción en el método de número de secciones y elementos por cada sección verás que los llama varias veces, es normal, que haga lo que quiera, mientras estén bien implementados la tabla aparecerá.

```
override fun viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(animated)
   self.view.addSubView(table1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que decir quien es el delegado, esto lo puedes hacer de dos formas:

1. Poniendo en el código `tableView.delegate = self` y `tableView.dataSource = self`
2. Desde el storyboard, seleccionas la tabla, mantienes pulsado el botón ctrl y con el click izquierdo del ratón arrastras hasta el controlador. Tal como te muestro en la imagen inferior, arrastras desde Table View hasta MuroVC y tienes que seleccionar dataSource y delegate.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]